# Opening a sequence

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I am currently using the Uipath Studio Community Edition, is there a way to use a sequence from a process in another process. I cant seem to find how to do it. The process only allows me to save an existing sequence but not open another sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the **Invoke Workflow file**. More [**here**](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/invoke-workflow-file).

So let's assume:

- you have a process with the file **Main.xaml**
- you have a process with the file **ExternalSequence.xaml**
- you want to use the **Main.xaml** and use the process from **ExternalSequence.xaml** in it
- now in the folder of **Main.xaml** create a new folder called **WorkFlows**
- move the **ExternalSequence.xaml** into the **WorkFlows** folder
- add the activity **Invoke Workflow file** in **Main.xaml** [image]
- into the parameter **WorkflowFileName** write **WorkFlows\ExternalSequence.xaml** (use the file search)
- run the **Main.xaml** now

Now the process of **ExternalSequence.xaml** should have been executed.

Comment: Good questions deserve good answers. I had a similar when I was starting. But I recommend you to go the good tutorials. They gonna show you all those stuff. But you need much time for them.